# Multiple <application> tags in faces-config.xml

Tags: java, jsf

It's a very simple question: can faces-config.xml file have multiple  tags (more like SHOULD they have)? I'm working in a JSF project and the faces-config.xml file has something like this:

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.jboss.seam.el.SeamELResolver</el-resolver>
    <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
    <message-bundle>customMessages</message-bundle>
</application>

<application>
    <view-handler>org.rivetlogic.crafter.core.jsf.CrafterFacesViewHandlerImpl</view-handler>
    <el-resolver>org.jboss.seam.ioc.spring.SpringELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

But I've never seen another JSF application with multiple `<application>` tags, and maybe this could be one of the causes of my problems (I kind of think the multpiple view handlers are involved).

Answer (score 1):

From [the JSF 1.2 schema](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd):

```
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element name="application"
                     type="javaee:faces-config-applicationType"/>
```

Multiple `application` elements should be OK, but there aren't any restrictions on the number of `view-handler` elements within an `application` element either.

The `ViewHandler` is pretty fundamental to how JSF works. The `ViewHandler`s may not be compatible (check their documentation) or they may be sensitive to load order (I don't think it is specified within a `faces-config.xml`). In the latter case, you can put them in separate documents and use the `javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES` init parameter to specify processing order ([see spec](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/reference/api/index.html)).